# Use colnames in a loop R

Tags: r, loops

I have many dataframes in a list and a vector with my new col names

```
nom_colonnes <- c("HEURE","REGIE", "ANTENNE", "MOYEN_DE_DIRECT", "ID_MOYEN", "SRV", "DESTINATION", "INSERT", "CDC_JRI", "REPORTER_INVITES", "LIEU", "ETAT","P_ou_R", "NOTE")
for (i in 1 : nb_files) {
        colnames(get(data_names[[i]])) <- nom_colonnes
}
```

> Error in get(data_names[[i]]) <- `*vtmp*`: impossible de trouver la fonction "get<-"
>   Traceback:

I'm lost... Anyone can help ? Thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

One option is to place the datasets in a `list` with `mget`, loop through the `list` of `data.frame`s with `lapply`, set the column names with 'nom_colonnes'

```
lst1 <- lapply(mget(data_names), setNames, nom_colonnes)
```

It is better to keep it in a `list`.  If we want to update the original objects, then (not recommended)

```
list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Hello, data_names is already a list, and I have an error : Error in mget(data_names): premier argument incorrect
Traceback:

1. lapply(mget(data_names), setNames, nom_colonnes)
2. mget(data_names)

Comment: @Otilrak  It was based on your code `get(data_names[[i]])`.  If the 'data_names' is the `list` of data.frame and not the object name as string, then remove the `mget` in the `lapply`

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I'm sorry I don't understand, I type :                                                                         
                                                                                                               
 'nom_colonnes <- c("HEURE","REGIE", "ANTENNE", "MOYEN_DE_DIRECT", "ID_MOYEN", "SRV", "DESTINATION", "INSERT", "CDC_JRI", "REPORTER_INVITES", "LIEU", "ETAT","P_ou_R", "NOTE") 


for (i in 1 : nb_files) {
        lapply(get(data_names[[i]]), setNames, nom_colonnes)
}     '                        And it don't work....No error but no changes

Comment: @Otilrak  Why you are using the `for` loop with `lapply`.  You don't need the `for` loop here if I understand correctly

Comment: So I have just to type : lapply(get(data_names), setNames, nom_colonnes) ? Thank you for your help I'm a newbie in R

Comment: @Otilrak  Yes, because in the `for` loop you are looping through the indices and extractig the datasets in the list.  Here, you are looping through the object iin the list itself

Comment: Grrrrrrrr ....                                                                                                                 
Error in names(object) <- nm: attribut 'names' [14] doit être de même longueur que le vecteur [1]
Traceback:

1. lapply(data_names, setNames, nom_colonnes)
2. FUN(X[[i]], ...)

Comment: @Otilrak  Can you please translate the error in english

Comment: nm: attribute 'names' [14] must be the same length as the vector [1] Traceback: 1. lapply (data_names, setNames, column_name) 2. FUN (X [[i]], ...)

Comment: @Otilrak  The issue is that some of the dataset have number of coluimns less than the length of  nom_colonnes.  Please check the list to see if that is the case